# CSS Encapsulation for Blazor Wasm

Tags: blazor, blazor-client-side

Do Blazor components support css encapsulation like Angular?
If so, how?
Else, what is the recommended approach for css per component? I guess encapsulation can still be achieved manually but is there a better support from the framework itself?

Answer (score 2):

After some searches, it seems like this is a pending feature
https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/issues/10170

but there seem to be a library as a workaround
https://github.com/alexandrereyes/BlazorScopedCss

Answer (score 0):

It has been added to Blazor in .NET 5 with the name: CSS Isolation.
You can apply CSS Isolation by naming a CSS file with the same as razor file.

for example, for `MainLayout.razor`  it's
`MainLayout.razor.css`

Note: you should place the CSS file in the same folder of the razor file.

It has some issues, for more details [read this article](https://docs.telerik.com/blazor-ui/knowledge-base/common-css-isolation).